# Return user id from onelogin

Tags: saml, onelogin

How do I get the return user id from the OneLogin SAML return values? I have looked at the consumer module but do not see any return values.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: What SAML toolkit are you using? PHP, Python, Ruby, Java?

Answer (score 0):

From the Saml response you can get the nameid.

Depending on how the Identity Provider was configured you would get an email or whatever else was decided. Usually is an email. The you can check against your db after the proper validation.

In Ruby and using OneLogin toolkit you instantiate:

```
OneLogin::RubySaml::Response
```